# Italianizzazione delle parole durante il fascismo

Tags: translation, history

Ho trovato in rete un'interessante tabella contenente molte parole straniere che, durante il ventennio, furono "italianizzate" (alcune con risultati a mio avviso abbastanza comici).

[image]

[image]

Qualcuno ne conosce delle altre che non appaiono in queste liste? Io ad esempio conosco "mescita", ovvero l'italianizzazione della parola "bar". Sapete quindi dove si potrebbe visionare una lista più completa?

Comment: Potresti dire da dove viene la tabella, per capire quanto sia affidabile? E comunque occhio, che alcune di quelle parole sono normali parole italiane preesistenti al fascismo, da “teppista” a “sciacquone”, per non parlare di “lista” o “soffitta”, e anche la tua “mescita” si usava già nell'Ottocento.

Comment: La tabella l'ho presa da un post di una pagina Facebook chiamata "Cripto", purtroppo loro non hanno citato la fonte...

Comment: Sono sorpreso che si siano presi la briga di italianizzare *boy scout* visto che il movimento scout era già stato dichiarato illegale dal fascismo nel 1928

Answer (score 5):

Un’altra parola forzatamente italianizzata in quel periodo era il cachet (equivalente della nostra attuale aspirina) che era tradotto come cialdino.

In [questo](http://paolo-padova.blogspot.com/2008/10/1940-solo-parole-italiane.html?m=1) articolo ho trovato anche i riferimenti normativi:

> “Divieto di uso delle parole straniere nelle intestazioni (delle
> ditte) e nelle varie forme di pubblicità” (legge 23 dicembre 1940, n.
> 2042)
>
> Per la classica incompetenza oggettiva delle Camere (ed anche delle
> loro “Commissioni legislative”) se ne delega l’elencazione alla Regia
> Accademia d’Italia (art. 3) che nel suo successivo Bollettino provvede
> a fornire l’elenco dei forestierismi banditi, suggerendo, inoltre, gli
> alternativi termini italiani da utilizzare.

Il sito [Cartoline dal Ventennio](https://cartolinedalventennio.it/layout/curiosita/188-l-autarchia-linguistica) riporta che sul Corriere della Sera del 21 giugno 1941, il “Bollettino di informazioni della Reale Accademia d’Italia” pubblicò un elenco di forestierismi con i relativi termini ed espressioni da adottarsi in italiano, approvati da una apposita commissione.

Le parole abrogate sono circa 500 tra Francesi e Inglesi:

> brioche: brioscia; carrè (uso gastronomico): lombata; champagne:
> sciampagna; croissant: cornetto; cyclostile: ciclostilo; dancing: sala
> da danze; dessert: fin di pasto; embargo: divieto, fermo; extra-strong
> (uso cartario): extra-forte; film: pellicola; hangar: aviorimessa;
> krapfen: bombola; hotel: albergo; goulasc: spezzatino all’ungherese;
> menù: lista; stop: alt; toast (pane tostato): pantosto.
>
> Principali parole (inglesi) nel mondo dello sport “abolite”: autogoal:
> autorete; bob: guidoslitta; bookmaker: allibratore; hockey: disco su
> ghiaccio; dribbling: scarto, scavalco; raid (aereo): transvolata;
> sprint: scatto; slalom (negli sports invernali): obbligata; tour:
> giro; trainer: allenatore.
>
> Il fascismo si spinge oltre, modificando persino nella grafia (a
> parità di pronuncia) alcune parole: alcool: àlcole; bidet: bidè; bleu:
> blu; casinò: casino; cognac: cògnac; mansarde (mansarda): soffitta;
> marron (colore): colore marrone; marron glacé: marrone candito; seltz:
> selz; wafer (biscotto): vafer; walzer: valzer.
>
> Ritocca persino due classicissimi termini storici dell’economia
> monetaria, che certamente largo uso non avevano nella società
> italiana: gold standard: base aurea; gold exange starndard: base di
> cambio aurea

In questo articolo sul blog KnowHow intitolato [Eja eja alalà! Le italianizzazioni del periodo fascista. Manuale del fascistese!](http://knowknow.it/eja-eja-alala-le-italianizzazioni-del-periodo-fascista-manuale-del-fascistese/) si trova una lista ancora più estesa con alcune ulteriori curiosità:

> **velivolo**, coniata da D’Annunzio, che sostituì macchina volante 
> **eja eja
> alalà** che fu il sostituto di Hip hip Hurrà (sempre per mano di
> D’Annunzio) 
> l’espressione "**essere una mezza cartuccia**" è tra le più
> amate espressioni di Mussolini per offendere i nemici

Il libro [Credere, obbedire, combattere: il regime linguistico nel Ventennio](https://books.google.it/books?id=dW4h0gOAILUC&pg=PA63&dq=Bollettino%20di%20informazioni%20della%20Reale%20Accademia%20d%27Italia&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcof23i9XbAhUBqywKHVT8C_YQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=Bollettino%20di%20informazioni%20della%20Reale%20Accademia%20d%27Italia&f=false) a cura di Fabio Foresti fornisce una descrizione puntuale dell'emanazione degli elenchi, nonchè delle commissioni che ebbero il compito di costruirli.

Infatti nelle pagine 62-63 del libro appena citato viene riportato l'articolo 3 del Regio decreto 20 marzo 1942-XX, n. 720 (grazie @DaG) ed il fatto che

> Gli elenchi comparvero a più riprese anche nei principali quotidiani.
>  Già da un anno, tuttavia, per disposizione del
> Ministero dell'Interno, all'Accademia d'Italia era stato affidato
> l'incarico di indicare le parole italiane da sostituire a quelle
> straniere. La commissione costituita dall'Accademia, che pubblicò una
> prima lista di sostituzioni nel maggio del 1941 era così composta...

Nelle note di piè di pagina (72) viene riportato integralmente il testo del bollettino citato a pag. 63.

Comment: Qui c'è il testo completo della legge (non l'elenco delle parole): http://www.normattiva.it/atto/caricaDettaglioAtto;jsessionid=hhVWdlA7iyJAdu5QZhWmgQ__.na1-prd-norm?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=1941-03-29&atto.codiceRedazionale=040U2042 , e qui la sua abrogazione: http://www.normattiva.it/atto/caricaDettaglioAtto?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=1946-07-03&atto.codiceRedazionale=046U0543&atto.articolo.numero=1&atto.articolo.tipoArticolo=0

Comment: Forse lì non è chiaro, ma l'art. 3 non è quello della legge, ma del successivo Regio decreto 20 marzo 1942-XX, n. 720 (si veda [qui](http://augusto.agid.gov.it/gazzette/index/download/id/1942158_P1), p. 2852).

Comment: Grazie per la risposta! Comunque quei link di normattiva.it non mi funzionano, mi appare una pagina con il seguente errore: "Attenzione: la sessione di ricerca é scaduta e per questo motivo sei stato riportato alla pagina iniziale".

Comment: Sembra che in quella pagina di ricerca tu debba inserire i riferimenti normativi indicando anno, numero della legge ecc

Comment: @Jack_Kirby: Pardon! Ecco il permalink alla legge (http://www.normattiva.it/uri-res/N2Ls?urn:nir:stato:legge:1940-12-23;2042!vig=); poi, da “aggiornamenti all'articolo”, trovi anche il decreto del 1946 con cui la legge fu abrogata. Mi sembra meno facile trovare invece un'analoga fonte per quello che deliberò l'Accademia d'Italia, e quindi per l'effettivo elenco delle parole.

Comment: Ho trovato che sul Corriere della Sera del 21 giugno 1941, il “Bollettino di informazioni della Reale Accademia d’Italia” pubblicò un elenco di forestierismi con i relativi termini ed espressioni da adottarsi in italiano, approvati da una apposita commissione. Ho cercato nell'archivio del corriere ma non riesco ad accedere alle edizioni di quel giorno.