# Esistono parole italianizzate in epoca fascista correntemente di uso comune?

Tags: word-usage, translation, history, foreign-words

Come è tristemente noto in epoca fascista molti termini stranieri di uso comune, tendenzialmente inglesi o francesi, furono italianizzati, diversi esempi possono essere visti in [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/italianizzazione-delle-parole-durante-il-fascismo).

Che io sappia però si tratta o di termini coniati ex novo e caduti velocemente in disuso alla fine del ventennio, ad esempio "sciampagna" per "champagne", o di termini preesistenti in italiano che dovevano sostituire un vocabolo straniero bandito, ad esempio "albergo" per "hotel".

Esistono parole che sono state coniate in epoca fascista per italianizzare un termine straniero e che sono ancora diffuse?

Comment: Il fatto che troppi termini stranieri (soprattutto inglesi) siamo usati nella lingua italiana non è un sentimento prettamente fascista. Più recentemente la questione e è stata posta anche in ambito linguistico senza coloriture politiche. https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/contenuti/l-italiano-ridotto-al-silenzio/7396

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: A occhio, mi sembra che una buona metà di quelle parole, da “autista” a “tramezzino”, siano ampiamente entrate nell'uso normale; persino varie di quelle coniate da D'Annunzio...

Comment: @DaG autista e tramezzino sono ottimi esempi, mettili in una risposta! Delle parole attualmente di uso comune nella tabella linkata non mi è chiaro quali sono state coniate nel ventennio e quali erano preesistenti

Comment: Hai ragione, @Quasi-isometry, è necessario distinguere; ho commentato un po' di fretta. In effetti vedo che anch'io in occasione di quella domanda osservavo che la tabella è un po' approssimativa e comprende anche termini preesistenti al fascimo.

Comment: Bisognerebbe armarsi di pazienza e cercare le varie parole citate nella risposta a quella domanda (ed eventualmente altrove) sul [Grande dizionario della lingua italiana](http://www.gdli.it/) e/o sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/) e/o sullo Zingarelli, che danno la datazione per ogni più o meno ogni lemma.

Comment: @Hachi: Giusto, e aggiungo, sugli anglismi in italiano, questo [articolo di Tullio De Mauro](https://www.internazionale.it/opinione/tullio-de-mauro/2016/07/14/irresistibile-l-ascesa-degli-anglismi), che non era certo un uomo di destra.

Comment: @DaG: Non credo sia necessario fare un elenco completo per rispondere alla domanda.

Comment: Duplicato? https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9577/70

Comment: @DaG: In [questo articolo](https://www.corriere.it/scuola/secondaria/cards/da-scudetto-tramezzino-come-d-annunzio-ha-cambiato-lingua-italiana/vate-contro-sommo-poeta.shtml) appaiono alcune delle parole presumibilmente coniate da D'Annunzio.

Comment: Concordo con i commenti di Hachi. In effetti, purtroppo, data la nostra storia, è facile confondere sentimento nazionale e fascismo (io stesso in questo post ho preferito dire sentimento nazionale invece che patriottico). Sono due cose completamente diverse. Dato che poi in Italiano abbiamo abbondanza di sinonimi sembra del tutto superfluo usare termini esteri (che se vengono italianizzati sono anche peggio vedi "schedulare") Aggiungo che l'esempio di "Albergo" "Hotel" non è forse il migliore dato che la parola albergo esiste in Italiano da sempre.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/43777805?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A1cf29219db05104dee345398f12b8c83&seq=29