# Quale di queste parole viene usata di più: "taxi" o "tassì"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, single-words, nouns, foreign-words

Di recente ho letto da qualche parte che la parola **il tassì** è usata anche per "taxi". L'ho sempre pensato, lo abbiamo usato così com'è: **il taxi**. Da quello che ho capito, entrambe queste parole sono utilizzabili. Tuttavia, ad esempio, a Torino, di solito usiamo la parola "il taxi". Mi chiedevo se c'erano altri posti in Italia dove invece di solito si usa la parola "il tassì". O al giorno d'oggi la parola "il tassì" è una forma obsoleta per "il taxi"? Sembrerei sbagliato se dico "il tassì"?

Comment: No, non sembra affatto sbagliato “tassì”. Personalmente, sono di Roma e a me è più familiare la forma “tassì”. È probabile che in certe parti d'Italia ne sia più diffusa una, in altre l'altra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come riportato da Treccani il **[taxi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tassi_res-287e1947-0036-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/)** prende il nome dall’abbreviazione di "taximètre" o tassametro.

> **tassì** (anche taxi o taxì) s. m. [adattam. del fr. *taxi*, abbrev. di
> *taximètre* («tassametro» e «vettura a tassametro»)]. – 1. Automobile
> fornita di tassametro, adibita al servizio pubblico: *chiamare,
> prendere un t.; posteggio di tassì.*

Nell’italiano di tutti i giorni si usa comunemente taxi, perché il termine [tassì](https://www.google.com/amp/s/latestabenfatta.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/il-fascismo-e-la-lingua-italiana/amp/) fu imposto dal regime fascista con [l’italianizzazione di tutte le parole straniere](http://knowknow.it/eja-eja-alala-le-italianizzazioni-del-periodo-fascista-manuale-del-fascistese/) ed è diventato poco usato, specie tra i giovani.

> Il periodo fascista italiano sostenne una battaglia linguistica contro
> l’esterofilia, parole non italiane ormai nel vocabolario. Furono circa
> 500 le parole “abrogate”, dalla cucina (predominata dal francese) allo
> sport (con predominanza inglese) fino ad altri campi della produzione e del lavoro.
>
> Di seguito un curioso elenco. In alcuni casi le parole
> sono arrivate nel lessico italiano attuale. In altri, dopo la guerra,
> sono lentamente state sostituite dai termini originari.

In questo altro quesito dal titolo *[Italianizzazione delle parole durante il fascismo](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/italianizzazione-delle-parole-durante-il-fascismo)* puoi trovare altri riferimenti.

Comment: Che grande informazione! È molto interessante. Grazie mille. Vedo che alcune parole del periodo fascista italiano sono ancora in uso oggi.

Comment: Ho aggiunto riferimenti ad un’altra domanda relativa all’argomento.

Comment: “Nell’italiano di tutti i giorni si usa comunemente taxi”: questa affermazione forse è vera, ma richiederebbe una fonte. Io non sono nessuno, ma mi è più familiare la forma “tassì”, e anche il Treccani lo mette come prima forma. Google sembra indicare che “taxi” sia più frequente, ma mi consola di essere in buona compagnia: almeno Calvino, Manganelli e Arrigo Levi usano “tassì” (e non erano esattamente dei fascistoni...).

Comment: Va bene, allora suppongo che diciamo che l'utilizzo cambia da luoghi a luoghi ma "taxi" sta diventando più comune?

Comment: @DaG: Anche Giorgio Bassani usa "tassì".

Comment: @tamuno: Non saprei, è difficile dirlo a orecchio. Ognuno di noi è influenzato dal modo in cui parla lui/lei e le persone che conosce o con cui è in contatto. Nessuno di noi ha un'idea precisa di come parlano e scrivono tutti gli italiani. Per questo chi compila grammatiche e vocabolari svolge studi statistici su grandi insiemi di dati.

Comment: Può darsi che sia così, @tamuno, però è molto difficile di rispondere a questa domanda basandosi su dati oggettivi. L'unico che mi viene in mente è usare Google Ngram, ma [questo strumento ha i problemi che si menzionano qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1225/).